# Looping through json subobjects and doing something with each "element"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html-table, row

I am a newbie with json arrays/objects.  I am trying to get to some subobjects within my .json file.  I have tried the suggestions on here, but I keep getting "undefined" results. Here is the .json --

```
{
  "DACcourses": [
    {
       "longTitle": "<a href='#'>Ammo-29 Electrical Explosives Safety for Naval Facilities</a>",
      "longDescript": "ammo-29.html",
      "atrrsLink": "Win 95+",
      "delMeth": "standard",
      "sked": [
        {
         "classNumb": "926",
          "startDate": "4/16/2012",
          "endDate": "4/20/2012",
          "location": "NMC Fort Worth, TX",
          "status": "scheduled",
          "emptySeats": "Availability"
        },
        {
          "classNumb": "001",
          "startDate": "6/4/2012",
          "endDate": "6/8/2012",
          "location": "McAlester, OK",
          "status": "scheduled",
          "emptySeats": "Availability"
        },
        {
          "classNumb": "920",
          "startDate": "6/18/2012",
          "endDate": "6/22/2012",
          "location": "Belle Chasse, LA",
          "status": "scheduled",
          "emptySeats": "Class Full"
        }
      ]}
]}
```

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.  so here is my code.  In the end I am trying to build table rows out of each of the 'sked' objects. But I am having problems with getting individual data elements to show in the console.  Here has been my attempts:

```
$('#content').on("click", "#catList tbody tr", function() {
                    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( this );
                    console.log( aData );
                    var scheduleData = aData.sked;
                    var catLink = 'catalog/' + aData.longDescript;
                    $('#fullDescript').load(catLink, function() {
                        if (!$('#fullDescript #offerings')) {
                            $('.enrollBTN').hide();
                        };

                        if ($(scheduleData).length > 0) {
                            $(scheduleData).each(function() {
                                for(var i = 0; i < scheduleData.length; i++) {
                                    /*var startDate = aData.sked.startDate[2];
                                    var endDate = aData.sked.endDate[3];
                                    var location = aData.sked.location[4];
                                    var classNumb = aData.sked.classNumb[1];
                                    var status = aData.sked.status[5];
                                    var emptySeats = aData.sked.emptySeats[6];*/
                                    //var item = scheduleData[i];
                                    console.log( aData.sked.startDate[2] );
                                    var html = "<tr>";
                                        html += "<td>" + item.classNumb + "<\/td>";
                                        //console.log( aData.sked[1].classNumb );
                                        /*html += "<td>" + scheduleData.endDate + "<\/td>";
                                        html += "<td>" + scheduleData.location + "<\/td>";
                                        html += "<td>" + scheduleData.classNumb + "<\/td>";
                                        html += "<td>" + scheduleData.status + "<\/td>";
                                        html += "<td>" + scheduleData.emptySeats + "<\/td>";*/
                                        html += "<\/tr>";
                                        //return scheduleData;
                                    };
                                $('#schedule tbody').append($(html));
                            });
                        };
                    });

                    $('#content').hide();
                    $('#fullDescript').show();
                });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would only need the **each** or **for** loop, but not both.  It also looks like there's some confusion in there on whether to use **item = scheduleData[i]** or not.  Try this:

```
if ($(scheduleData).length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < scheduleData.length; i++) {
        var item = scheduleData[i];
        var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + item.endDate + "</td>";
        // ... etc
        html += "</td>";
    }
}
```

Just as a PS, I'd recommend looking into a JS templating tool like [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).  This would allow you to separate data from display template, so you could eliminate the parsing code.  It would look something like this:

```
var template = "{{#sked}}<tr><td>{{endDate}}</td><td>{{location}}</td></tr>{{/sked}}";
var html = "<table>" + Mustache.render(template, aData) + "</table>";
```

Comment: dbaseman,  Thank you for the education.  I knew I was putting too much into it.  My problem just seemed simpler than I was making it.  But I noticed a problem when I put it into action.  I am only seeing the last sked item being rendered.  I proved this by commenting out the last two sked objects in my .json file.  Reran my application.  Now it rendered just the first sked object.  So somewhere, I am missing an outer loop or I am starting my loop at the wrong place. Any ideas??

Comment: check out www.serco-hrc.com/crseCatalog/index.html.  Select Course Catalog from either menu.  Go to second ("next") page of data.  Then select "Ammo-29 Electrical Explosives Safety for Na...".  There should be 3 course offerings that it brings up. Got me baffled.  Code looks correct.  tony

Answer (score 0):

> I must be doing something fundamentally wrong

Yes you are.

When you use `.each` loop, you refer to the current element by `this` keyword. So you do not need the `for` loop. Or, if you want the `for` loop, you do not need the `.each` loop. In my opinion, use the `for` loop. `.each` is just an overhead in this case.

**UPDATE:** @dbaseman gave you exactly what you need :)

**UPDATE 2**: Please try the following code. Basically its same as that of dbaseman, but dbaseman's snippet missed closing the `<tr>` element.

```
if ($(scheduleData).length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < scheduleData.length; i++) {
        var item = scheduleData[i];
        var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + item.endDate + "</td>";
        // ... etc
        html += "</tr>"; // should close the <tr> here
    }
}
```

Comment: Nikhil, (that's Sanskrit, I believe).  But on another note, I followed dbaseman's suggestion, and it works like a charm.  But it only renders one table row, no matter how many schedule objects there are. Do I need to rethink my json format/schema??  I tried wrapping @dbaseman "for" loop in another "for" loop, but that went back to a return of undefined. Tony

Comment: @EnergeticPixels I'm pleasantly surprised! Yes, It is sanskrit :) I think your schema is OK you need not change it, its just the `for` loop that we need to correct

Comment: Yah, I have prior knowledge of the language.  I am a retired US Navy linguist (Russian language).  I did notice the </td> that was in the wrong place when he sent it to me.  I automatically put a correct </tr> in its place.  And I just noticed that all these examples do not have any escaped characters.  My code did.  so I went back and removed the "\" from closing tags.  Did not help.  The code is building a correct <tr> line, it is just not building a new <tr> line with each iteration.  Tony

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. It finally dawned on me that my current code was not telling the system to build a brand new <tr> line.  I moved this line of code: [code]$('#schedule tbody').append($(html));[/code] to inside the for loop and everything works as advertised.  I get all three course offering listings.  Thank your for all the good help!!  dhanyawādāh    @dbaseman - thank for for getting me going down the correct 'road' to success!  Tony

Comment: Yes I did read that in your profile! Glad I could help. Sadaiwa Swagatam :)